# Which is more efficient "Int to Char" or "Char to Int"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables A and B. The key variable is in integer format in Table A and in character format in Table B (It is all made up of numbers though). So, I can either convert the column from table A to varchar or the column from Table B to int.

Query1:

```
select a.*
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b on Cast(a.key as varhcar(10))=b.key
```

Query2:

```
select a.*
from tableA a 
inner join tableB B on a.key=cast(b.key as int)
```

My question is which among these queries is the most efficient and why?

Comment: Fix the table definition instead. If you have to `cast` to `join`, something is usually very wrong.

Comment: A join that involves any sort of function call (including CAST or CONVERT... whether explicit or implicit) will kill performance. Columns you join on should, ideally, have the exact same type.

Comment: I do understand that the data model needs fixing. It is however out of my hands in this scenario, as I only have read access to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to convert from char to int for these reasons:
1- comparison operations in computers basically done between numeric values.
2-the process will be faster.
3-more precise results.

Comment: Its worth noting however that all ints can be converted to chars, but most chars cannot be converted to ints

Comment: I am certain that the data is made up of all numbers. I am going to go with the char to int conversion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is quite bad advice.  Can you provide a reference that converting a string to a number is faster?

Answer (score 2):

You should fix your data model!

This has nothing to do with the efficiency of the type conversion.  Basically, if indexes cannot be used SQL Server will use a nested loops join (I would love to hear that they actually use a hash-join, but I don't recall seeing that occur in this case).

So, if you have no indexes, it really makes little difference.

If you have an index on one table -- well, you want to avoid the conversion on that column.  For example, this query:

```
select a.*
from tableA a inner join
     tableB B
     on a.key = cast(b.key as int)
```

Could use an index on `a(key)`.  The execution plan would scan `b` and use the index to "lookup" the value.  However, it would not use an index on `b(key)`.

All that said, fix your data model.  Foreign key relationships should be properly declared -- and that requires that the types match.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do understand that the data model needs fixing. It is however out of my hands in this scenario, as I only have read access to the data.